# Edmond Tanair scoring criteria

Tags: archipelago-solo-exp

What exactly is Edmond Tanair's (scenario #03) scoring criteria? Is it "a mountain per tile score you a victory point"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted Ludically and here is the designer answer:

> You need to count the number of visible regions (hexes) that you have discovered and legally placed on the archipelago containing some mountains.
>   If it has some textured mountains on the tile then it's counted as one, no matter how much mountain there is on the tile. Some islands for example also have mountains, such an island tile would be then worth 1 point towards your ranking.